# Simple url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite part of an url as I've changed a CMS and still want Google to find my articles.

I have:

```
www.mywebsite.com/vision
www.mywebsite.com/vision/40/some-article-name
```

and want to rename them:

```
www.mywebsite.com/news
www.mywebsite.com/news/40/some-article-name
```

Any hints as to the re-write rules or where I can look?  I'd like to change the rules in my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
# redirect /vision to /news
RewriteRule ^vision$ http://www.mywebsite.com/news [R=301,NC]
# redirect /vision/bla-bla to /news/bla-bla
RewriteRule ^vision/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/news/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA]
```

In theory (and practically) these 2 rewrite rules can be combined, but then if you have URL that starts with "vision" (like this, for example: `/visions/hurray`) then such rule may redirect wrong URLs. Therefore I have done it via 2 rules which is much safer.

Comment: I still couldn't get this to work.  Will keep trying and see if I can work out why my .htaccess file doesn't seem to be re-routing.

Comment: @Matt Can you please show the contents of your `.htaccess` file? And where it is located (I guess in the root folder).

Answer (score 0):

Try: `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html`

or: `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html` if you want to change links in the html content returned to the browser.

Here is an example of how I might do the rewrite I think you're after...

RewriteRule ^(.*)/vision/(.*)$ $1/news/$2

This may be to broad of a rewrite scope in which case this may be better...

`RewriteRule http://www.mywebsite.com/vision/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/news/$1`

Also learning the basics of regex will be a needed skill for doing any complex rewriting IMO.

Hope that helps.